# Adding Simperium to existing Core Data project crashes with Assertion failure

Tags: ios, core-data, simperium

What I have:

- iOS 5.1 Core Data project.
- I use Mogenerator for my Core Data classes.

What I did:

- I tried to add Simperium to my app and followed the tutorials (1) and (2)

What I get:

```
Simperium starting... 
*** Assertion failure in -[SPCoreDataExporter addMembersFrom:to:], /Users/kineticpoet/dev/simperium-ios-private/Simperium/SPCoreDataExporter.m:95
```

What I tried:

- Read through (3)
- Delete App on simulator (5.1) and install new. Same problem.

I have not tried to install on device, since the data on device is important to me.

What else could I try? And what exactly is the problem here?
Thank you.

[(1) https://simperium.com/tutorials/simpletodo-ios/](https://simperium.com/tutorials/simpletodo-ios/)
[(2) https://simperium.com/docs/ios/](https://simperium.com/docs/ios/)
[(3) https://simperium.com/docs/reference/](https://simperium.com/docs/reference/)

Comment: That's a very specific third-party product.  You should probably go to them for support.

Comment: Generally you are totally right. This time though they ask for asking support questions on stack overflow. Otherwise I would have gone another route. See https://simperium.com/contact/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your Core Data model have a Binary attribute? These aren't fully supported yet, so you'll need to manually disable them if they're present: [Simperium couldn't load member data (unsupported type)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571694/simperium-couldnt-load-member-data-unsupported-type)

Comment: It does have one. I will try this out. Thank you.